# Mapeamento OneToMany uni-direcional com 3 classes usando 1 unica classe

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Boa noite,

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
@Entity
public class Endereco {
   private String logradouro;
   private String numero;
   private String cep;
   private String bairro;
   private String complemento;
}

@Entity
public class Cliente {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Endereco> enderecos;
    // Outros atributos...
}

@Entity
public class Fornecedor {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Endereco> enderecos;
    // Outros atributos...
}

@Entity
public class Procurador {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Endereco> enderecos;
    // Outros atributos...
}

@Entity
public class Fiador {
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Endereco> enderecos;
    // Outros atributos...
}
```

Como eu devo criar um relacionamento para que todas as classes Cliente, Fornecedor, Procurador e Fiador usem a mesma tabela "ENDERECOS" ou algo parecido?

Comment: Qual o problema com o código que você postou?

Comment: Assim, não sei se isso é bom, em `endereco` teria que ter uma chave composta primary key onde o código da relação e um outro campo que tenha a informação da onde vem esse código. Imagine você se tiver só um campo de relação pela chave primária uma hora o mesmo id de fornecedor pode se chocar com qualquer outro causando erros. Se fosse para fazer um teste Endereco.Codigo e Endereco.Entidade onde o Id gerado vem junto com o nome de quem enviou (Fiador ou Procurador ou Fornecedor ou Cliente) pode até simplificar colocando letras, seria uma forma!

Comment: Você precisa ter um código único para suas classes, que serão suas primary keys no banco de dados. Endereco precisa de um id. Evite usar chaves compostas quando usar um ORM. Todos funcionam melhor com ids únicos, apesar de alguns suportarem chaves compostas. Garanta a integridade referencial com constraints, mas sempre adicione um coluna que será a chave composta, ou o "Object Id". Como não utilizo muito jpa não sei se a anotação @Entity já adiciona um Id. Se for o caso, já está resolvido, não?

Comment: Resolvido o problema do id, seu endereço pode ser referenciado pelas demais classes dessa forma mesmo. A FK (Foreign Key) estará nas tabelas que referenciam endereço, portanto diferentes tabelas podem referenciar o campo ID de endereço para garantir a integridade referencial. Com essa modelagem, inclusive, você poderá compartilhar o mesmo endereço com entidades diferentes.

Comment: Acho que a maneira mais orientada a objetos que pensei até agora foi criar uma classe intermediária que contém uma lista de endereços e atributos em comum entre as classes ai em cima e, ao persistir endereços no banco, eu antes persisto esta classe que passa como chave estrangeira seu id numa coluna na tabela endereço. Assim não existirá duplicidade de id tanto na classe Cliente quanto na classe Endereço e ainda por cima saberei quantos Endereços existem em cada classe Cliente, Fiador, Fornecedor e Procurador. Aceito sugestões sobre essa minha solução.

Comment: @andref O problema é que eu não quero criar uma tabela auxiliar (@JoinTable) para cada entidade relacionando com endereços.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você não quer tabelas auxiliares (*join table*), é necessário usar herança e registrar a chave estrangeira na tabela `Endereco`. A superclasse seria algo como:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class ObjetoComEndereco {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="objetoComEndereco")
    private List<Endereco> enderecos = Lists.newArrayList();
}
```

Note que o `mappedBy` é necessário. Se não for usado, o Hibernate vai criar uma tabela auxiliar e usar `UNION` para recuperar os endereços.

As demais classes estendem `ObjetoComEndereco`. Por exemplo:

```java
@Entity
public class Cliente extends ObjetoComEndereco {
    // Outros atributos...
}
```

A classe `Endereco` muda para:

```java
@Entity
public class Endereco {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private ObjetoComEndereco objetoComEndereco;
}
```

O Hibernate vai criar apenas 5 tabelas:

```sql
create table cliente (
    id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)

create table endereco (
    id bigint not null,
    objeto_com_endereco_id bigint,
    primary key (id)
)

create table fiador (
    id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)

create table fornecedor (
    id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)

create table procurador (
    id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)
```

Uma consulta por procurador, por exemplo, produz este SQL:

```sql
/* criteria query */ select
    this_.id as id1_4_0_,
from
    procurador this_
```

Como a lista de endereços é *lazy*, o Hibernate faz outra query na hora de acessá-la:

```sql
select
    enderecos0_.objeto_com_endereco_id as objeto_c2_1_0_,
    enderecos0_.id as id1_1_0_,
    enderecos0_.id as id1_1_1_,
    enderecos0_.objeto_com_endereco_id as objeto_c2_1_1_ 
from
    endereco enderecos0_ 
where
    enderecos0_.objeto_com_endereco_id=?
```

Se ela for *eager* a consulta muda para:

```sql
/* criteria query */ select
    this_.id as id1_4_1_,
    enderecos2_.objeto_com_endereco_id as objeto_c2_1_3_,
    enderecos2_.id as id1_1_3_,
    enderecos2_.id as id1_1_0_,
    enderecos2_.objeto_com_endereco_id as objeto_c2_1_0_ 
from
    procurador this_ 
left outer join
    endereco enderecos2_ 
        on this_.id=enderecos2_.objeto_com_endereco_id
```

Comment: Resolveu o meu problema, obrigado @andref!